# Set bar chart interval to fractions below 1.0

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to set the bar chart intervals to values less than 1, such as 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, etc.

However, I'm not able to get this to work: it always starts from 1, 2, 3, etc. I tried resetting the interval but am unable get the desired output.

My SSRS version is 2008 R2.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, change the scale of the x or y axis? The "Interval" of an axis is the tick marks shown on an axis, and you can change that by selecting the axis and then changing the Interval property to 0.2. I tried it, it works. 

Can you give a brief example of the data, and what data you have in the Category groups (X axis) and which you have in the SUM Values (Y axis)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the series that you want to create an interval to. 
IN this case it is vertical axis.

Go to the vertical axis properties and in the axis options you have Axis range and interval. Go to the Interval property and put in the interval that you want to achieve. it is 0.1 in the above case.

I have Maximum number as 2.I have attached an image for your reference. [image]

--The interval can be seen on the left hand side of the property windows.